# Thermal radiation of flowing gas inside cilinder

Tags: thermal-radiation

Problem:

Understanding the concept of flowing gas radation.

For my study i am designing a model of the heat transfer in a large verticale cilinder where flue gas with a temperature of 1400K flows. The cilinder is split in layers where it is assumed that all properties are constant, the heat transfer for each part is calculated and so the total heat duty is known. Dimensions of the cilinder are from 1-3 m diameter and height of 3-10 m.

I am having problem grasping the concept of thermal radiation inside this closed environment. The equation i am using now is:

$P = A \sigma \varepsilon ( T_{gas}^4 -T_{surface} ^4)  $

- $a$ = surface area
- $\sigma$ = Stefan–Boltzmann constant
- $\varepsilon$ = emissivity

Right now i am using the emissivity of steel but the value for this varies greatly and not sure what value to choose. Tt works against my intuition to choose a fixed value because, the flue gas has a high concententration of $CO_2$ and $H_2O$ both are gases that absorb radiation. Shouldn't there be a relation between the distance travelled in the gas and the total thermal output?

Reasoning: 
 With a larger cilinder diameter the photon has a longer path to travel so more chance of being absorbed by the flowing gas.

Is this method sufficiently accurate or am i indeed missing parameters?

Comment: They key word you're looking for is http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Radiation_hydrodynamics . In RHD, you couple the photon transfer equations with the internal energy equation from hydrodynamics. The equations can be solved for the photon field as function of space and time.

Comment: From what i understand radiation hydrodynamics does not play a role in this problem because the radiation is of significant low intensity. Also i should add that the dimensions of the cilinder are from 1-3 m diameter and height 3-10m.

Comment: Well, you're asking about radiating fluids. Of course you can treat this problem in a static way and only solve the equations of radiative transfer.